# PHP real time application

Tags: websocket

I have to create a little AJAX chat in my web application and I'm dealing with problem of real-time communication between JavaScript client and PHP server.

I want my js client to be able to catch new messages from the server as quick as possible. My first idea was to create AJAX request for example each 5 sec. to see whether there are new messages.

However, I'm not sure what happens if my application use for example 1000 people, it must be huge load to Apache httpd.

I also know about technique called 'long-polling' request, but when I tried that locally on my server, I've completely shooted down my Apache (I've read sth about problems with apache and long-polling). The next way I know about is WebSocket.

However, is it true that I have to be able to open port on webserver to use it? Because on regular web hosting, I thing it's not possible and I cant change any Apache/PHP settings on my hosting.

Do you have any suggestions how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use websockets, you better have full control over your server as you may be facing the need to start and stop the websocket daemon whenever it's needed.

I wouldn't recommend using "regular web hosting" because of its restrictions.

I think that you are looking for "virtual server providers", that provides you full control over the server you manage. You should look at [Amazon Web Services](http://aws.amazon.com/fr/). There are many others that you may find.